# How to list up variables assigned to a specific section in an elf file?

Tags: elf, readelf

How can I list up variables allocated in a specific section in an elf file?
For example, if I do `readelf -t vmlinux`, I can see the section informations (start offset and the size, of course in virtual address) so I can see where the `.data..percpu` section starts and for how long.

```
Section Headers:
  [Nr] Name              Type             Address           Offset
       Size              EntSize          Flags  Link  Info  Align
  ....
  [18] .data..percpu     PROGBITS         ffffffc0105cb000  0054b000
       0000000000011948  0000000000000000  WA       0     0     64
```

Also I can list up all the symbols using -s option which shows the address and size of all the symbols. I could combine those info with the section info to list up all the variables in .data..percpu section. But this will take some effort and I thought there should be a simple command that lists up variables in a specific section. Can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every symbol has the section index to which it belongs in the `Ndx` column.

To find all symbols matching section 18, do this:

```
readelf -Ws vmlinux | cut -c60- | grep ' 18 '
```

Comment: Wow thanks again! (Then 'readelf -Ws vmlinux | awk '$7==18{print}'  also works). I didn't know there are so many percpu variables.